# When using an Operator Modal Timer, how do i change the time period such that it executes every 5 seconds?

Tags: python, operator

I'm trying to use a modal operator timer to get a piece of code to execute every 5 seconds. Currently all i want is for it to print a statement every 5 seconds however, in the future, this will be changed to create a new object every 5 seconds.

Currently i use the following which prints the statement multiple times a second.

```
import bpy


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            print("5 seconds has passed")

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(1.0, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

How do i change this to run once every 5 seconds?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/131934/15543

Answer (score 1):

The event timer has a property which defines how often your modal function will get called with the timer event, just change the value accordingly in the execute function:

```
time = 5.0
self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(time, window=context.window)
```

Comment: how often the modal is called or when timer event is true?

Comment: it will get called for every occuring event (such as ESC for cancelling), but only every 5 seconds from the timer event

Comment: To clarify re comment: If a `print("bar")` is added under `def modal(...` and a `print("foo")` in `if event.type == 'TIMER'` it will print a lot of bars between each foo.  Feel that your answer is implying modal is being called every 5 secs which AFAIC is not the case.

Comment: you're right, modal gets called more often. I included the timer event in my answer, is that enough?